# Selenium WebDriver like tool for desktop application

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, desktop-application

I am struck up in my below task, hope this idea will be very useful for many.
In my company they use several **Health Monitoring tool** and we do the **Health Checks** manually.
We have a separate health check plan and process, where we go to Web Applications like Site Scope or open certain jars like **Spectrum CA** (runs as a JNLP file) and check for the server status/health data manually.
As we have more than 50 monitoring tools like that I suggested to automate the Health Checkups.

Initially I was suggested to do the automation using **Python** but I am a **JAVA Web developer** so I moved to **Selenium/Jsoup** and use *Web-*scraper** concept to fetch the information and do the health checkups. I am able to do considerable progress using Selenium to automating the manual Health Checks using the **Web Application**.

**Problem**: As I mentioned we also need to do certain health checkups using jar, desktop apps or jnpl file (applet), I am not sure on how to proceed in automating these. We are not supposed to use any paid tools or unreliable freeware which record and replay the manual desktop operations.

I do not have any idea on those, so can you please suggest me a tool or testing automation tool for these Desktop applications where I should be able to LogIn into it, Enter some text in the TextBox, Search, filter, navigate and get a value and finally verify whether the health is green ?

**Note**: Few of the application are legacy application so they don't use any api calls.

Comment: Have you looked at AutoIT?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 free tools which can cater to your needs which can be used alongside Selenium w/ java:

1) AutoIT - good for window based applications

2) Sikuli - an image based automation Tool

Answer (score 1):

> I do not have any idea on those, so can you please suggest me a tool or testing automation tool for these Desktop applications where I should be able to LogIn into it, Enter some text in the TextBox, Search, filter, navigate and get a value and finally verify whether the health is green ?

For the above question, Winium can be used for desktop app automation. It is similar to Selenium. You can write code in java to automate the process. below is the git link for Winium.

https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop

I was looking at FlaUI, you can have a look at this as well. This works with c# though

https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI